# Non-sequential event bubbling onClick vs addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
function Example() {
  const containerRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const targetElement = containerRef?.current
    const stopPropagation = (e: MouseEvent) => {
      console.log('propagation stopped at parent div')
      e.stopPropagation()
    }

    targetElement?.addEventListener("click", stopPropagation);

    return () => 
      targetElement?.removeEventListener('click', stopPropagation)
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      <div onClick={() => console.log('child')}>
        <div onClick={() => console.log('grandchild')}>
          <button>click</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the above snippet, `'grandchild'` and `'child'` should appear in the console first, respectively, after clicking the button. However,  `stopPropagation()` handler gets invoked before both `onClick` inline-handlers (which are no longer executed after `.stopPropagation()`.

In my understanding, the click event should bubble from:
`button -> grandchild -> child -> containerRef (event stops bubbling from here)`

Does the `.addEventListener` behave differently in contrast to `onClick` attributes? It seems that in the snippet above, the `.addEventListener` handlers get invoked first before `onClick` handlers do.

For a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-leaf-9vnrq

I've tried doing something similar with HTML: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-wildflower-cf0jx

```html
  <div id="parent">
  <div id="child" onclick="window.alert('child');">
    <div id="grandchild" onclick="window.alert('grandchild');">
      <button onclick="window.alert('button')">
        click
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  const parent = document.getElementById("parent");

  parent.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.alert("parent");
  });
</script>
```

In the above snippet, it works just as intended, click bubbles from: 
`button -> grandchild -> child -> parent (event stops bubbling from here)`

Comment: Propagation of event from parent to child occurs in capturing phase, so if you want to stop it you have to do it in capturing event listener, i.e. addEventListener('name', fn, {capture: true}) (or just truthy third param).

Comment: I've read about capturing, too. Applying it in the snippet above doesn't work. In this case, ```targetElement.addEventListener('click', handler, true)``` has no impact on the sequence, both child and grandchild div's `onClick` is still not invoked.

Answer (score 2):

React uses SyntheticEvent mechanism handled by React itself. Which means that the real event has already propagated by the time you interact with it in React. Therefore, you cannot mix SyntheticEvents with regular JS events, because it leads to unexpected behaviors.

What you can do is stop the propagation of SyntheticEvent in your component

```
...
  // onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} instead of addEventListener
  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}> 
      <div onClick={() => console.log('child')}>
        <div onClick={() => console.log('grandchild')}>
          <button>click</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I have tried this as a solution, the `ref` is intentional as it's an abstraction (an external library attaches handlers instead of manually adding `onClick = {e => e.stopPropagation()}`. But it's clear to me now that it's impossible given how React batches events independently of the native DOM's `addEventListener`. Thanks for the input 

Comment: If you want to integrate React component with some external library or another framework then you should checkout out [Web Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html) It allows to use React components as DOM elements and integrate them with native DOM API